# Access a member of a sibling class instance

Tags: c++, oop

What is the Proper way to access c1 from Child2?

To get some context, imagine Child1 and Child2 being textboxes, and Child2 needs to make a decision with c1.member current value. This is just some dummy code that will look more clear:

```
class Parent
{
public:
    Parent()
    {

    }

    ~Parent()
    {

    }

    class Child1
    {
    private:
        int i;
    };

    class Child2
    {
        Child2()
        {
            // somehow access c1.i;
        }

    };

private:
    Child1 c1;
    Child2 c2;
};
```

Comment: its unclear what you're trying to do, but you can either provide public getter in Child1 or declare Child2 as friend

Comment: Have `Parent` pass a pointer or a reference to its `c1` to whatever method in `Child2` wants it.

Comment: There is no special relationship between `Child1` and `Child2` here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Is one better than the other? I mean pointer or reference. The project allows up to C++14 so I'd like to have the cleanest solution if there's something offered up to that version.

Comment: References existed prior to C++14. And neither a pointer nor a reference is "better" than the other. They serve similar, but not identical purposes. In most cases either one or the other will work well. In some cases one will be slightly more convenient than the other; specifically if it's possible that the method in question may not always need or want its sibling for whatever it's doing; in which case one can simply pass a `nullptr`; but when passing a reference you don't have a similar option. But if you want to require, by contract, a valid object, you can enforce it by using a reference.

Comment: First, you need to set up the relationship between `Child1` and `Child2`, using either a reference or a pointer. If the association is unconditional, you set it up in the constructor; if it is conditional, you set it up in the method of either `Child1` or `Child2` where it will be used. But, if you find yourself with a circular reference, i.e. `Child1` depends on `Child2`, and vice-versa, you should consider delegating the decision logic to `Parent`, then associate `Parent` to both `Child1` and `Child2`. I hope this helps.

Comment: @RWRkeSBZ with your help and the rest of you I was able to get to a working solution. If you like, see the answer I posted below, thanks for your invaluable help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the helpful comments I got on the question, here is a sane solution:

```
class Parent
{
public:
    class StepTwo;

    Parent():
        // we're initializing c2 here because it does not have a default
        // constructor.
        c2(c1)
    {

    }

    ~Parent()
    {

    }

    class Child1
    {
    private:
        int i;
        // Making Child2 a friend class, allows it to access access private
        // members of Child1.
        friend class Child2;
    };

    class Child2
    {
    public:
        Child2(Child1 &r_c1)
        {
            pC1 = &r_c1;

            // pC1 can access everything from Child1 with ease.
        }
    private:
        Child1* pC1;
    };

private:
    Child1 c1;
    Child2 c2;
};
```

Comment: The semi-colon on line ~7 shouldn't be there.

Comment: @davmac Thanks for catching that. I added some more comments, to make things clearer.